# fatal error app/mage.php line no 547 in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

Fatal error: Class 'Junaidbhura_Ccavenue_Helper_Data' not found in /home/www/ngx/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 547

please help me.

Comment: Check your helper name should be case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

That's because your helper either doesn't exist at: **app/code/local/Junaidbhura/Ccavenue/Helper/Data.php** or you haven't defined it in your module /etc/config.xml file:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <ccavenue>
            <class>Junaidbhura_Ccavenue_Helper</class>
        </ccavenue>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Or your module is not activated in **app/etc/modules/Junaidbhura_Ccavenue.xml**